# Kendo Grid Server Side filtering sending null as a filter object to the backend

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Using Kendo AngularJS and ASP .NET MVC I am trying to send the filters object of a grid to the backend. However any filters made on the frontend are null in the request even though I set serverFiltering to true.

[image]

```
grid.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
              url: "api/foo",
              dataType: "json",
              type: "POST"
              }
     },
     schema: {
          data: "data", // records are returned in the "data" field of the response      
          total: "total"
    }
    });

//set grid to filterable
grid.filterable = {
    mode: 'row',
    operators: {
         string: {
                 contains: "contains"
                 }
     }
 };
```

I took a look at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764678/kendo-grid-server-side-filtering-and-not-working?rq=1) but it did not help me as I wasn't able to replicate the solution listed as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

On the controller side the "DataSourceRequest" mapped out the form values differently (e.g. inspecting the POST request on the frontend sent "filter" instead of "Filters" as an argument. I had to create a new model class that binded the proper values